# Why aren't all properties of an object being shown in the variables section in the debugger

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I'm using XDebug with the Visual Studio Code debugger on some PHP code, and the Variables section is not showing all of the properties on one of my objects.  The screenshot below shows that if I add `$this->_data` to the Watch section, that property does exist.  However, `_data` is not shown as a property in `$this` in the Variables section.  Why isn't Visual Studio Code showing all of the properties in `$this`, and how do I get it to show all of them?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that property happen to be the result of a `__get` magic function call?

Comment: Thank you, you're right.  It's a protected property.

Answer (score 8):

This issue is related to whether the attribute/field is private/protected or not.

You must tell XDebug to forward detailed information such as private fields to your IDE via the command show_hidden=1.

In VSCode with [Felix Beckers php debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) extension, you can add this setting through the `launch.json` by adding the field `xdebugSettings` (see their doc for details)

The following worked for me:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9090,
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_children": 200,
                "max_data": 512,
                "max_depth": 4,
                "show_hidden": 1 //< show/forward private field info to the IDE
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**NOTE:** Remote config doesn't seem to support -l for any of the above settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting

```
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', -1);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', -1);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', -1)
```

You sholud also read the explanation on xdebugs settings: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In this case it turned out that `_data` was actually a protected variable, which is why it wasn't being shown.

Comment: protected variables should be shown. If it doesn't, report a small but self contained bug with source code to https://bugs.xdebug.org

Comment: Looking at xdebug's docs (https://xdebug.org/docs/display#var_display_max_children), it looks like these settings are not valid when using "Step Debugging" (which I believe VSCode is using).